# My program doesn't want to write in a text file after DLL call

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, cout, ofstream

I have a DLL which expose a function :

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllimport ) __stdcall int EP_ProtectedStringByKey( char* Key, char* Left, int Len);
```

Head of the C++ file :

```
typedef int (*GetString)(const char *Key, const char *Str, int Len);
```

With this code, everything works fine. The program write in the "*example.txt*" what it should write.

```
GetString _GetSTR;
int longueur;
string my_string;
const char *pmy_string; 
HINSTANCE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary("my.dll");
_GetSTR = (GetString)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "EP_ProtectedStringByKey");
ofstream myfile("example.txt");
longueur = _GetSTR("key_421", NULL, 0);
cout << "Taille : " << longueur << endl;
myfile << "Size : " << longueur << endl;
my_string.resize(longueur); // resizing the string
pmy_string = my_string.c_str(); // Pointer to pmy_string


// ---- _GetSTR("key_421", pmy_string, longueur); ---- 

myfile << "Another line.\n";
myfile.close();
FreeLibrary(hInstLibrary);
```

Now if I add this line of code :

```
_GetSTR("key_421", pmy_string, longueur);
```

My data is well print on the screen with :

```
cout << "Data : " << pmy_string << endl;
```

But **NOTHING** is write anymore  in the file "*example.txt* ("Another line" isn't write anymore). It's like after fulling the *my_string* variable, my program refused to write in file. But strangely it show the content of *pmy_string* on the screen.

I suppose I'am doing something wrong but I can't figure what...

Thanks for help,

Comment: You are not initializing `pmy_string` to point to a properly allocated block of memory.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I have forgotten to copy two lines of code which were presents in my code.

Comment: `std::string::c_str` returns a `const char*`, modifying it is undefined behaviour, use `std::string::data` instead, your `GetString` `typedef` probably should match the actual function definition too

Comment: You need to specify `__stdcall` in your `typedef` for the function pointer: `typedef int (__stdcall *GetString)(const char *Key, const char *Str, int Len);`. Without this, you'll be getting stack corruption, because there is a conflict as to whether the called function or the calling module should clean up the stack (I think in your case, *both* will attempt it) - then you enter the realms of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Adding **__stdcall** to the **typedef** works like a charm. 

But I don't understand why using std::string::c_str is undefined behavior.
std::string::c_str() gives me the pointer to the beginning of the char array ? So I could write in it without problem no ?

Thanks for all,

Comment: @MelectronVolt. "I can write to it without a problem". See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str where it explicity states "Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior." So I guess the question is whether you consider undefined behaviour to be a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks and sorry to had bothered you. It was just for understanding. Have a nice day and thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid two undefined behavior, I need to :

1. Change the typedef to precise the calling convention

`typedef int (*GetString)(const char *Key, const char *Str, int Len);`

In

```
typedef int (__stdcall *GetString)(const char *Key, const char *Str, int Len);
```

2. Dpn't use **std::string::c_str()**  cause in [CPP-Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)  *"Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior."*

`pmy_string = my_string.c_str(); // Pointer to pmy_string`

In

```
pmy_string = my_string.data(); // Pointer to pmy_string
```